# How to use PHP to return an image to Objective-C?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, ubuntu, nsurlconnection

I have a script in PHP that grabs an image on my server. I want it to be able to send it to Objective-C. I have tried numerous methods that I found to return the image and none of which seem to work. I have the image stored on my server in a directory and I want to be able to send it to my app. This is my current code:

The code just doesn't change the image. I'm not sure how to check if PHP is sending the image properly.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myserverurl"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *body = @"username=benr783&password=testpassword";
    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connect start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `data` in `didReceiveData` really an image? Does the PHP responses with image content type?

Comment: @Raptor how do I check this?

Comment: you should understand the delegate of nsurlconnection first or simply use block which is easier to handle

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. You appear to be assuming that you will receive the entire image with a single call to your `didReceiveData` method. That's not a valid assumption. (In fact, unless your images are trivially small, this is actually unlikely.)

   Before beginning your connection, instantiate a `NSMutableData` object, in `didReceiveData`, you should merely append the received data to that `NSMutableData`, and then in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, once you've combined all of the data received in the multiple calls to `didReceiveData` into a single `NSMutableData`, you can now take that final `NSMutableData` and try to convert it to an `UIImage`.
2. BTW, only call `start` if you use the rendition of `initWithRequest` with the `startImmediately` option and with that option set to `NO` (which you only use in special circumstances). In this case, just remove that `start` call.
3. You should check to see if the data received is really an image. For example, in `didReceiveResponse`, make sure the `NSURLResponse` has a `statusCode` of 200. Make sure that `didFailWithError` was not called. Etc.

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
       if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
           int statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
           if (statusCode != 200) {
               NSLog(@"statusCode != 200; it is %ld", (long)statusCode);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. You might want to watch this transaction take place using [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and make sure it's an image in response, etc.

Comment: If the image comes down multiple times, how do I get it all at once?

Comment: You can't control that. You must assume it will come down in parts. So, create `NSMutableData` property, instantiating that property to `[NSMutableData data]` before starting the connection, have `didReceiveData` merely append the received data to your `NSMutableData`, and only convert it to a `UIImage` in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: Or, as chings228 suggested, abandon this complicated delegate-based approach and use something like `sendAsynchronousRequest`, which is much simpler...